# How to merge two colums by id in excel?

Tags: excel

I have two colums with id in every one of them.
How do I "merge" the two columns so that I can have values that exist in either column A or B in column C, with repeating the values?

As you can see in colume A I have uniqe id and in colume B I have duplictes id.
I need that in colume C I would have all of B's ids (include the dupicate) and the ids that appers in A but not in B.

```
A                             B                       C
---------------            ---------------         ---------------
121.45.183.129             124.86.1.183             121.45.183.129    
124.86.1.183               130.102.0.178            124.86.1.183  
130.102.0.178              130.116.32.125           130.102.0.178
130.116.32.125             130.116.32.91            130.116.32.125 
130.116.32.91              138.194.132.208          130.116.32.91
138.194.132.208            138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
144.136.121.153            138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
144.137.61.21              138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
202.122.132.4              138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
202.181.31.4               138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
203.166.247.160            138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
203.17.154.70              138.194.132.208          138.194.132.208
                                                    138.194.132.208
                                                    144.136.121.153
                                                    144.137.61.21
                                                    202.122.132.4
                                                    202.181.31.4
                                                    203.166.247.160
                                                    203.17.154.70
```

Thank You!

Comment: The sequence in merging is important as in your example? Also, how do you want to go about doing this? Formula? VBA?

Comment: The sequence  is not important, i was thinking doing it with formula.
Thanks!

Comment: `i was thinking doing it with formula` What have you tried then?

Comment: =IF(A2=A1, "",A2) but its not working

Comment: You are trying to merge the values in A and B but your formula has no relation or reference to B.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a new ColumnA with:

```
=COUNTIF(C:C,B1)
```

in A1 copied down to suit. Sort Z>A ColumnsA:B, select the range in ColumnB next to `0` in ColumnA and drag this to C13.